# how to move subviews inside a super view

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

how to move subviews inside a super view (using osx 10.6) using mouse?
i have programmatically  created five NSimageView's as subviews using for loop..
how to select and drag each imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    NSEnumerator *subviews = [[self subviews] objectEnumerator]  ;
    NSView  *hitView    ;
    NSLog(@"hit");
    fHitView = nil  ;
    while (hitView = [subviews nextObject]) {
        NSRect  frame = [hitView frame] ;       

        if (NSPointInRect(aPoint,frame))
            if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[DraggableView class]] && ![(DraggableView *)hitView dragEnabled]) {
                return hitView   ;
            }
            else    {
                fHitView = hitView  ;
                fHitPoint = aPoint   ;
                fFrameWhenHit = [hitView frame]   ;
                return self   ;
            }
    }

    return nil  ;
}


- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if (fHitView != nil)    {
        NSPoint locationInWindow = [theEvent locationInWindow]  ;
        NSPoint locationInMySelf = [self convertPoint:locationInWindow fromView:[[self window] contentView]]    ;

        [fHitView setFrame:NSOffsetRect(fFrameWhenHit,locationInMySelf.x - fHitPoint.x, locationInMySelf.y - fHitPoint.y)]  ;
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES]  ;
    }
}
```

insert into subclass of NSview and change the class name of NScustomView class as subclass name...

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, you'd want to make your subviews drag sources, and make your target view a destination.  This means implementing something like the NSDraggingSource and NSDraggingDestination protocols.

Take a look at Apple's Drag & Drop documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop

Comment: [DragItemAround](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragItemAround/Introduction/Intro.html) how can i add a controls such as NSButton etc., instead of that dragable rect.

Comment: i have filled a image in the frame ,is it possible to create another frame [ dragItemAround](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragItemAround/Introduction/Intro.html) coding

Comment: [NSDraggingSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSDraggingDestination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) only available from OSX 10.7

Comment: The general pattern of having one object implement a drag source protocol and another object implement a drag destination (or drop target) is pretty solid, and is used by a number of operating systems.  On iOS you're on your own, but check out the protocols Apple uses on the Mac and you can create something similar for your own app.  You may also find something that implements this for you - check out http://dragkit.org/ for example.